# Speech to Text Chrome webkit with Java Script - How to do a console log on Special Keywords?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I would like to use speech to text from chrome web kit... It works fine but I would like to to have a console log on certain keywords. I tought that I can do it like this....

```js
if(textInput.includes('?'))
{console.log('Yes,it works');}
```

My HTML / JS looks like this... My problem is that I have not really an idea where to put this piece of code...

```html
...
<label for="textInput">
<div id="textInput" class="input responsive-column" type="text" onkeydown="/*globals CanvasJS */
            ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this)"></div></label>




<button onclick="startConverting();"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></button>
<script type="text/javascript">



 var r = document.getElementById('textInput');
 function startConverting (){

  if('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window){
 var speechRecognizer = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
 speechRecognizer.continuous = true;
 speechRecognizer.interimResults = true;
 speechRecognizer.lang = 'en-IN';
 speechRecognizer.start();

 var finalTranscripts = '';

 speechRecognizer.onresult = function(event){
          var interimTranscripts = '';
          for(var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++){
           var transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript; 
           transcript.replace("\n", "<br>");
           if(event.results[i].isFinal){
            finalTranscripts += transcript;
           }else{
            interimTranscripts += transcript;
           }



          }

          r.innerHTML = finalTranscripts + '<span style="color#999' +interimTranscripts + '</span>'; 
 };

 speechRecognizer.onerror = function (event) {

 };



}else {
 r.innerHTML = 'please update google chrome ';
}

 }



</script>
...
```

Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var r = document.getElementById('textInput');
    function startConverting (){

        if('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window){
    var speechRecognizer = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    speechRecognizer.continuous = true;
    speechRecognizer.interimResults = true;
    speechRecognizer.lang = 'en-IN';
    speechRecognizer.start();

    var finalTranscripts = '';

    speechRecognizer.onresult = function(event){
          var interimTranscripts = '';
          for(var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++){
            var transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript; 
            transcript.replace("\n", "<br>");
            if(event.results[i].isFinal){
                finalTranscripts += transcript;
            }else{
                interimTranscripts += transcript;
            }



          }
         if(finalTranscripts.includes('?')){
           window.alert('It works');
}
          r.innerHTML = finalTranscripts + '<span style="color#999' +interimTranscripts + '</span>'; 
    };

    speechRecognizer.onerror = function (event) {

    };



}else {
    r.innerHTML = 'please update google chrome ';
}

    }



</script>
```